# POO. Asociación y Agregación

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy empezando a aprender POO. El script siguienet, muestra una relación de asociación.

```
# Asociación
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def addNums(self):
        return self.b + self.c

class B:
    def __init__(self, d, e):
        self.d = d
        self.e = e

    def addAllNums(self, Ab, Ac):
        x = self.d + self.e + Ab + Ac
        return x #Añadimos el return

ting = A("yo", 2, 6)
ling = B(5, 9)

print(ling.addAllNums(ting.b, ting.c))

print(ting)
print(ting.a, ting.b, ting.c)
```

Entiendo bien el método addNums(), en el que x es la suma de los objetos d y e de la clase B y de los objetos b y c de la clase A.

Para que fuera una agregación en lugar de una asociación, éste método tendría que ser:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, d, e, A):
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
        self.A = A

    def addAllNums(self):
        x = self.d + self.e + self.A.b + self.A.c
        return x

ting = A("yo", 2, 6)
ling = B(5, 9, ting)

print (ling.addAllNums())
```

En esta clase B se inicializa una instancia de la clase A, en su propio constructor, como atributo.

En éste método no entiendo la forma de seleccionar los objetos b y c de la clase A, comparándolo con el mismo método en el caso de asociación.

En x, ahora, llamamos al atributo A de la clase B haciendo self.A, pero, por qué la llamada al tributo b de la calse A, se hace ahora con self.A.a en lugar de self.Aa?

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estas dos formas de conseguir ambos objetos?. Agradeceré sus comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes acceder a un objeto de una clase sin un `.`. self(la clase en si misma).A(la clase A que está almacenada dentro del self).a(Variable a)

Haciendo `Self.Aa` estarías accediendo al objeto Aa del self, y el self no tiene ningún objeto llamado Aa, lo que necesitas es acceder al objeto `a` guardado dentro de `A`.

Debes considerar cada `.` como una llamada o acceso a la variable contenida en el objeto anterior al `.`

En el primer ejemplo que pones

```
def addAllNums(self, Ab, Ac):
        x = self.d + self.e + Ab + Ac
        return x #Añadimos el return
```

la función declara los parámetros Ab y Ac, es decir, no estás accediendo a variables del self, ni a valores de otra clase, tan solo estás accediendo a las parámetros que le pasas al llamar a la función: `print(ling.addAllNums(ting.b, ting.c))` si te fijas, está llamando al método addAllNums desde la el objeto ling, lo que Python hace en ese caso es llamar al método `addAllNums(ling, ting.b, ting.c)`, en este caso el self hace referencia al objeto ling, y luego le pasa directamente los números almacenados en `ting.b` y `ting.c`.

Recuerda que, cuando se trabaja con métodos de clase, en python se pone siempre `metodo(SELF)` aunque luego no se pasa realmente el parámetro self, ya que el intérprete asume que el objeto que llama al método es el self (`objeto.metodo`).